# Wiring switch+outlet combo?

Tags: electrical

The box used to have just a switch controlling an overhead light. It has 1 white and 1 black (Canadian wiring btw). I got a plug and switch combo and want the plug to always be on, with the switch only controlling the overhead light. How should the wiring look?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You don't have a constant hot conductor at the box. You have a switch loop:

[image]

You can probably pull a cable from another nearby box to power the outlet, depending on how the device is set up. You want to keep the circuits separate. If it only has one hot screw this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make this work is to replace the 2-line wire with 3-line wire (will have white, black and red).

1. Black - Bring your hot in with this. If this is a regular combo outlet (like [this one](http://www.leviton.com/en/products/5225)) it should have a shared hot with a breakaway tab (leave the tab in)
2. Red - Hook the switch up to this
3. White - Hook the outlet up

In your fixture box

1. Black - Hook this to the incoming hot
2. White - Hook this to the common neutral (all the other white wires should be nutted together)
3. Red - Hook your fixture to this wire

Comment: Maybe not the *only* way, but a good answer otherwise.